# Check if remote server is in listen mode through socket programming in java

Tags: java, sockets

How do I check if a remote server is listening on particular port or not with socket programming in java?

I need to check this so that I can initiate a connection with that server on that specified port.

Comment: The simplest way would be to attempt connection to that port and check for the result.

Comment: Whats wrong with just trying to connect to see if you can?

Answer (score 3):

Connecting to it *does* check that it's listening. You don't need to do that again yourself.

In general the best way to know whether any resource is available is just to try to use it. You still have to handle the error when you use it, so why write all that code twice? And checking first introduces a timing window during which the situation may change. And either you use a different technique to check, which may yield a different result, or you use the same technique, which is just redundant.

Don't attempt to predict the future. It isn't necessary. It arrives soon enough anyway.